# Why does gin + SocketIO give me EOF errors?

Tags: go, socket.io

Why does gin + SocketIO  give me  EOF errors?
**gin** + **go-sicketio**
**my code**

```
Server.OnConnect("/", SocketIo.Connect)
....
go func() {
        if err := Server.Serve(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("socketio listen error: %s\n", err) // 启动socket.io服务
        }
    }()
defer Server.Close()
```

**err's code**

```
...
2022/09/05 12:18:18 没有找到用户2
2022/09/05 12:18:18 socketio listen error: EOF
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find an answer on page https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/439

the problem may occurs when you read from the Request Body twice.